Rocket.chat Ubuntu Error 413 File too large
I'm running rocketchat on Ubuntu and when I use the chat I can't upload files to the chat. it shows like it's uploading then nothing happens. When I try to upload a profile picture I can't either. It shows this:  413 Request Entity Too Large
I made sure the limit size is -1 for unlimited and still get this issue.

How large is the image? What happens if you try a smaller one?

If you changed the setting to -1, you may need to restart the server for that change to take effect.

I try smaller low quality image and they upload but any regular images or even a basic mp3 wont upload
